# favorite button ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have problem with my ajax code it didn't work i don't know why.
here is my code:
this php code is in other page that named favourite.php

i have problem with my ajax code it didn't work i don't know why.
here is my code:
this php code is in other page that named favourite.php

```
 $test = $_SESSION['ww'];

    $x = $_SESSION['x'];
     $SelectQry2 = "select * from favorites where User_Id = ".$test." and User_Post = ".$x."";
       $slc = mysqli_query($link , $SelectQry2);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($slc)> 0){
      $DeleteQry = "DELETE from favorites where User_Post = ".$x."";
      $del = mysqli_query($link , $DeleteQry);
      }else{
      $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      $InsertQry = "insert into favorites";
      $InsertQry .="(`User_Id` ,`User_post`, `url`) VALUES";
      $InsertQry .=" ('$test' ,'$x', '$url')";
      $fav = mysqli_query($link, $InsertQry);
      }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){ 
 e.preventDefault();
 $("button").on("click", function(){  
 var data = $(this).serialize();
   $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
 data: data,
    url: "favourite.php", 
    success: function(data){ 
      alert("Data Save: " + data); 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
      alert("An ajax error occurred: " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
    }
  }); 
});
});
```

```html
<button>favorite</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: what is the result in browser developer tools network section response for ajax?